# Puppet replacement with regsubst

Tags: puppet

I have some strings that are paths like "/path/example" and I would like to substitute the slash "/" for dash "-". The result would be "-path-example"

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#regsubst

Comment: You already mention `regsubst()` in the question title, and that could indeed be applied to the problem you present.  What is it that you actually want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are confused about how to escape the slashes? Anyway, this does what you want:

```puppet
# test.pp
$myvar = regsubst('/path/example', /\//, '-', 'G')
notice($myvar)
```

And:

```
▶ puppet apply test.pp
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): -path-example
Notice: Compiled catalog for ... in environment production in 0.02 seconds                                                                        
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

- Note that the `/` needs to be escaped in the regex as I did there.
- You need the `G` flag to ensure all of the matches are replaced.